# Android ADT "WindowUtils" class missing

Tags: android, google-glass

I just created a new Android application project in Eclipse. The min-sdk is set to 16 and the target-sdk is set to 20. Following the documentation on Google Glass, I need to add the following line of code in my onCreate() method:

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS);
```

However, Eclipse reports that WindowUtils class is not found.

Is there a library that I need to add to the project? The project creation wizard did not ask me for one. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you compile with the wrong target.
Can you check your `project.properties`?

Make sure you set your target like this:

```
target=Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19
```

Also, try updating your Gdk.